# Copying URDU text from HTML into XML file?

Tags: xml, perl, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to extract the "Urdu" text from the local html files. I am getting the text and putting them before XML tags in my Perl script. now in my XML file I am getting following sort of text in between tags,

```
<v no="29"> &#216;&#167;&#179;&#8221;&#226;&#8364;&#226;&#8364;</v>
```

I don’t know whether it is something to do with utf-8. Those html files works fine. All the Urdu text looks OK.  Any thoughts?

```
<br><SPAN class="verse" id="29">29 </SPAN>  اور خُدا نے کہا کہ دیکھو میں تمام رُوی زمین کی کُل بیج دار سبزی اور ہر درخت جس میں اُسکا بیج دار زمین کی کُل بیج دار سبزی اور ہر درخت جس میں اُسکا بیج دار پھل ہو تمکو دیتا ہوں ۔ یہ تمہارے کھانے کو ہوں ۔ 
 <br><SPAN class="verse" id="30">30 </SPAN>اور زمین کے کل جانوروں کے  لئے اور ہوا کے کُل پرندوں کے اور اُن سب کے لِئے جو زمین پر رینگنے والے ہیں جن میں زندگی کا دم ہے کُل ہری بوٹیاں کھانے کو دیتا ہوں اور اَیسا ہی ہوا۔ ۔
```

i am extracting using regex from my documents, not online
m#(\d+)\s</span>(.*)\s#i etc.
I am using "print" to write in xml file.
Perl 5.18.2
Linux Mint 17 64-bit
Thanks

Comment: What version of perl? What have you tried so far? Are you cutting and pasting; extracting the text using perl; using an editor? What platform are you on ? You need to show your work. It probably  *does* have something to do with Unicode, encoding, etc. so try looking at [`perlunitut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) and  [`perlunicode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html), but in order to help you people  are going to need more information.

Comment: plus one for the idea, I never thought about it, i will give it a try

Comment: What'a the character set in the HTML input?

Answer (score 2):

How are you writing the XML? Are you using a module or just `print`? If you could give us the original Urdu text we would have a better chance of figuring out what happens. The text as you have it, encoded with numerical entities, is `Ø§³”â€â€` which looks like double-encoded text, but it's hard to figure it out without knowing what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

These are HTML entity codes. They are useful for portability, especially if your HTML is hosted on a web server which is configured to serve some legacy single-byte encoding (commonly ISO-8859-1) by default.

Decoding these is literally a one-liner in any reasonably high-level language, but you should probably be using a library which shields you from this and all the other intricacies of modern real-world HTML.

Comment: libraries? can you tell more about it?